# Set Fanspeed of NVIDIA GPU on headless Ubuntu server at boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, gpgpu

We use a headless system (a monitor-less CyberPC gaming machine) in my high performance computing research lab running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-141 generic) containing a NVIDIA GTX 1080 (as a GPGPU) on v384.130 drivers.
I often notice that the fans are either not running, or only run intermittently.

I don't like that, for a number of reasons.

I'm aware of how to set the fanspeed using the NVIDIA XServer settings with coolbits=4 (see ["How can I change the nvidia GPU fan speed?" on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/299648/518756)).
However, this only seems works when a user is logged into an XServer instance on the machine.

How can I set the fanspeed (or at least a minimum speed) at boot?